# How to pass json object in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, vue.js, axios

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="bee-plugin-container"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  // import axios from "axios";
  // import Bee from "@mailupinc/bee-plugin";
  import $ from 'jquery'
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        info: null,

      };
    },
    mounted() {
      var bee;

      var endpoint = "https://auth.getbee.io/apiauth";
      var payload = {
        client_id: "<client>", // Enter your client id
        client_secret: "smesVY4mhFdfxvgF", // Enter your secret key
        grant_type: "Basicbmdll" // Do not change

      };
      $.post(endpoint, payload)
        .done(function(data) {
          var token = data;
          // continue initialization here...
          console.log('token: ', data);
          // Define a simple BEE Plugin configuration...
          var config = {
            uid: token.userName,
            container: 'bee-plugin-container',
            language: "en-US",
            // eslint-disable-next-line
            onSave: (jsonFile, htmlFile) => {
              // eslint-disable-next-line
              const params = {
                layout_json: jsonFile,
                layout_html: htmlFile,
                campaign_id: 1,
              };
              console.log('saving...', params);
            },
          }
          window.BeePlugin.create(token, config, function(instance) {
            bee = instance;
            // You may now use this instance...

            var template = {
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
            };

            bee.start(template);
          });

        });

    }
  };
</script>
<style>

</style>
```

How to pass json object in Vuejs?

I made an api call, to call the bee-plugin instance. where i need to pass the json object, I have no clue like where i need to pass the json obj.

below is the code where the api call is working fine, but issue is with how to pass json obj.

```
var template = {
              // Any valid template, as JSON object
              
            };

            bee.start(template);
```

Codesandbox link:-
https://codesandbox.io/s/bee-plugin-in-vuejs-rjn99?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Why not save the template in your public/static folder and fetch it ?

Comment: @MohibArshi  This is my codesandbox link 
https://codesandbox.io/s/bee-plugin-in-vuejs-rjn99?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: @MohibArshi The Api call is working fine but, bee instance is not calling

Comment: I don't see any initialization of bee plugin anywhere. In its docs you can see we have this code ```const beeTest = new Bee(); beeTest.getToken(clientId, clientSecret)```

Comment: Yes that's right. if possible can u help me with some code. So that it will useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to initialize the Bee plugin and create its instance. And use the instance to start the template as per the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mailupinc/bee-plugin).
You may do so on the `mounted` method.

```js
mounted(){
  const beeInstance = new Bee();

  const config = {}; // Your configs
  const template = {}; // Your template

  // ...

  beeInstance
    .getToken(payload.client_id, payload.client_secret)
    .then(() => beeInstance.start(config, template));
}
```

Here is the link to the working [codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/bee-plugin-in-vuejs-forked-w923v?file=/src/App.vue:57410-57551).